# Unable to access changed variable value inside nested functions

Tags: javascript, nested, closures

I have a huge business logic to be executed in both of the below functions but I struck in one issue. I know its related to closure but how to solve I am not aware of. Can you through some light.

```js
function func1() {                
                var x = false;
                console.log('before going inside func '+x);
                func2(x); 
                console.log('After coming outside => '+x);
 //Instead of true its displaying false
            
}

function func2(x)
{
              x = true;
              console.log('inside func => '+ x);
}

func1();
```

My original problem is like below

```js
function func1() {                
  var x = false;
  var y =1;
  var z=3;

  func2(x,y,z);    
  
  console.log(x,y,z);
  //INSTEAD OF true,10,30; its displaying false,1,3          
}

function func2(x,y,z)
{
   x = true;
   y=10;
   z=30;
              
}

func1();
```

Comment: So what problem are you trying to resolve..  It's not a closure issue btw.

Comment: @Keith, I added comments please check once. Noted: its not closure issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` parameter of `func2` is completely distinct from the `x` variable in `func1`. When you do `func2(x)`, the **value** of `x` is passed to `func2`, not some kind of reference to the variable. (Some languages do that; JavaScript does not.)

To return information out of a function, use `return` in the function, and use the function's return value where you call it:

```js
function func1() {
  var x = false;
  console.log('before ' + x);
  x = func2(x); // *** Note `x =`
  console.log('after ' + x); 
 }

function func2(x) {
  return true;
}

func1();
```

Perhaps a better example, using the value of `x` in `func2`:

```js
function func1() {
  var a = 1;
  var b = 12;
  console.log('a before: ' + a); 
  a = func2(a);
  console.log('a after:  ' + a); 
  console.log('b before: ' + b); 
  b = func2(b);
  console.log('b after:  ' + b); 
 }

function func2(x) {
  return x * 2;
}

func1();
```

If you have complex information to return, return an object with properties for the complex information (or pass in an object, and have `func2` fill in properties on it, it depends on the use case [and whether you're adhering to immutability paradigms]).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Croweder, is that only way ? passing object to the function and retrieve it.

Comment: @Abhi - There are three ways to pass information from a called function `a` (your `func2`) to a calling function (`b`, your `func1`): 1. Using a return value. This is **by far** the best way. 2. Passing in an object, and having `a` modify the state of the object (set properties, etc.). 3. Having `a` modify variables that both functions *close over*. #3 is by far the worst way -- hard to read, hard to maintain, hard to test.